# from lxml.html import fromstring module not found, lxml installed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, lxml

I am trying to import `from lxml.html import fromstring` in VSCode but I am getting the error:  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'` I have installed lxml with `pip install lxml`

I am using a virtual environment and VS code

```
Version: 1.52.1 (user setup)
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18363
```

My python version is 3.7.4 and I forced a reinstall of the wheel file

https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/7e/e74f03e6e56184f8af8e33055223cb1d8ecec91a7084ca626b8070b2c67f/lxml-4.6.2-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2014_aarch64.whl

This did not solve the issue, and the 32bit wheel version wont work on my 64 bit machine.

The only solutions I could find were the install from wheel and also try the 32bit version.

Comment: I have googled for an answer but have found nothing useful - the direct wheel installation and also trying to use the 32bit version are what I have tried.

Comment: -When you enter "_python --version_"(or _python3 --version_), is the Python version displayed on the VS Code terminal consistent with the Python in the lower left corner of VS Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You @JillCheng I resolved the issue by deleting the PATH variable I had in the system environment - it was being used with VScode and conflicting with the virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code shows that the module cannot be found because there is no such module in the currently selected Python environment, Please refer to the following command to check the module:

1. Please use the command "`pip --version`" in VS Code to check whether the Python currently used in the terminal is consistent with the Python displayed in the lower left corner of VS Code:

   [image]

   If it is inconsistent, please use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new VS Code terminal, then it will automatically enter the selected Python environment (Python shown in the lower left corner).
2. We can use the command "`pip show lxml`" to check its installation location:

   [image]
3. Run:

   [image]

Reference: [Python environment in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment).